# iPhone Map - practical max number of points in MKPolyLine

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkpolyline

I'm displaying a route on a map using MKPolyLine - this works fine. What I'm not sure about, and can't find anything on SO relating to, is what is the best approach when I have a very large number of points? For instance, if I have 60000 points, would it be a good idea to take only 1 in every 100 if the entire route is on screen, and re-calculate every time the user pans/zooms the map? Or does the Map Kit automatically optimize based on the current zoom level & how much of the route is visible? I have heard about "Least Squares" optimization, & I'm currently looking into that too.

The difficulty for me at the moment is that my test devices are quite new with lots of memory, so I can't test on less capable devices. The simulator seems able to cope with any amount of points.

Comment: Check out Apple's Breadcrumb sample.  The custom overlay changes the number of points based on the zoom level.  Not sure whether MKPolyLine does the same, but you should note that overlays are rendered into bitmaps before being displayed so it's not redrawing the line every time.